# python threading not starting / super slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

```
def main():
    proxies = [i for i in open('proxies.txt', 'r+').readlines()]
    instance = Pair('0x852E3A65d0cD8561eDc0927012412D60AAAa9a4C', proxies)

    num_worker_threads = int(500)
    threading.Thread(target=instance.set_title, name="set_title").start()

    for i in range(num_worker_threads):
        threading.Thread(target=instance.get_pair()).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am trying to add threading to my program however no matter if I put 500 or 1 thread in it is still the same speed. The function its running on is a While True loop with a try and a get request in it.

If you have any ideas on what im doing wrong please help :)

Comment: Did you mean: `target=instance.get_pair`?

Comment: Also, what are the `target`s doing? If they're doing CPU-bound work, threading won't be of much help here. You'll need to use multi-processing unless you're doing IO-work.

Comment: I took the statement from the OP of: `get request` to mean network-bound work.

Comment: @quamrana That's true. The names of the functions don't sound very IO-based though unless `get` and `set` are "GET"/"POST" requests or something.

Comment: yes you were right, I feel stupid for that but thanks alot. To clarify it was `target=instance.get_pair` that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow on what  Carcigenicate said...

The first thing you need to be aware of is that python is single-threaded. The threading library gives the impression that you are getting true multithreading, but you are not.

That being said... If you have a task that is spending a lot of time waiting for something to happen (typically IO bound operations such as user input, reading data from a file, or getting data from the internet), then this is where the threading library shines... It allows you to do stuff while waiting on other functions. However, at its core, it is still just running on a single thread. So if your functions are not IO-bound, then you should expect NO improvement by using the threading library.

In that case, you could try to use the multiprocessing library, but tread carefully as it can be difficult to get right...

Comment: It should be noted for the sake of clarity that Python isn't single threaded. It's multithreaded, but the execution of byte-code within threads is synchronized across all threads. You can have multiple threads running at once, but only one can execute code at any time.